# How to dynamically set array length

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code that lets me input an array of 10 doubles, and I want to change it so I can have the option at start to choose how many inputs I want to make (max 10).  The code I have is below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HowTo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
        double num[]=new double[10];
        double i=0;

        for (i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            num[(int) i]=in.nextDouble();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you create `i` outside of the for loop? And as a double?

Comment: Since you're genuinely using arrays, I removed references to "list" in your question.  Lists and arrays are two *very* different things and it's important for your sake to not confuse the two.

Answer (score -1):

You are not using a list, you are using an Array.  Use a list (try ArrayList).  You don't specify an initial size and it will grow as you add stuff.  When you are done it converts easily to an Array if that's really what you want.

replace:

```
double num[]=new double[10];
```

with:

```
List<Double> num=new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
num[(int) i]=in.nextDouble();
```

with

```
num.add(in.nextDouble());
```

When you want to read an item, use num.get(itemNumber)

Now I advise you stop here, there is no reason to go back to arrays--the List collection is fine--but if you really must:

If you want num[] to be A Double array, then at the end do:

```
Double[] array = num.toArray(new Double[num.size()]);
```

If you actually want it to be a "double" array (note the lower case), convert the previous array like this:

```
double[] doubleArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(array);
```

Comment: This code lets me input up to 10 doubles, then it ends. I want to "ask" me at the start how many inputs I want to do, 10 max. Is this possible to happen with a change on this one, or should I look it in a different way ? Thanks for your time !

Comment: Use an ArrayList.  That's exactly what it's made for!  You don't want it to ask, you just want it to grow when items are added.